# Why is this code wrong?

Tags: java, log4j, migration, slf4j, logback

I am migrating a code from Log4J to slf4j backed by logback 1.0.13.

How can I translate the following code to slf4j ?

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    // ...  

    ConsoleAppender stderr = new ConsoleAppender();
    stderr.setTarget(ConsoleAppender.SYSTEM_ERR);
    stderr.setLayout(layout);
    stderr.addFilter(new CurrentThreadLogFilter());
    stderr.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    stderr.activateOptions();

    Logger loggerRECORD = getLoggerRECORD();
    loggerRECORD.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    loggerRECORD.setAdditivity(false);
    loggerRECORD.addAppender(stderr);

    Logger root = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(Level.WARN);
    root.addAppender(stderr);

    // ...

    private Logger getLoggerRECORD() {
         return LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.company.MyClass");
    }
```

I don't know what to use in place of `setLevel`, `addAppender` and `setAdditivity` methods.

Comment: I don't think the SLF4J Logger interface supports the methods you're looking for, because they're implementation specific. The actual implementation (Logger class in Logback) supports setLevel() and setAdditive(). 

What does the getLoggerRECORD() method do? Does it always return a Logback logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, if you want to be "pure SLF4J", you cannot (and should not) configure your logger via code. The configuration details are implementation-specific. (ref: [slf4 FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#configure_logging))

If you are certain you are going to use Logback, you have two options:

1. Use Logback-specific configuration files outside of your code; or,
2. When you get your Logger (from the LoggerFactory), you know it is
   going to be a Logback implementation. So, cast it to that, and then
   use the extra methods it supports, over and above the interface from
   SLF4J.

The first (config files) is easier to change. I would advise going that route.

If you want to go the second route, you could change the import so that we're dealing with the actual class from Logback, not the interface from SLF4J. Also, you could add a cast when the Logger is returned by the LoggerFactory.

Having done this, you will find that the Logger class now supports the setLevel() and setAdditive() methods you were looking for. See [Logback javadocs](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/index.html) for more info.

Comment: I'll go for the first route.

Comment: Note that if the logback.xml file is not expressive enough, you can use Groovy.  This should allow you to do whatever you want.